# Distinguishing types based on constraints

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, type-families

Firstly, I'll explain a simplified version of my problem, then the actual problem.

Consider the types of `max` and `(+)`

```
max :: Ord a => a -> a -> a
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Notice they only differ by their constraint. I want to write a type family F so I've got something like:

```
f :: a -> F a
```

So that

```
f max
```

has a different type to

```
f (+)
```

Now the actual problem.

Given (from my [polydata](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/polydata-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Poly.html#t:Poly) package):

```
data Poly (c :: * -> Constraint) where
  Poly :: { getPoly :: (forall a. c a => a) } -> Poly c
```

I want to be able to write `mkPoly (+)` without explicitly specifying the constraint myself.

I figure perhaps I could make a type family that converts types into constraints, as it's a fairly mechanical process.

That's the background behind my question, but I thought asking a simpler problem would be a good start.

Comment: I think this is undecidable in general; note that `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`, but equally validly it has type `(Num a,Eq a,Show a) => a -> a -> a`. What should the result type of `F (Num a => a -> a -> a)` be in this case?

I just realized this is somewhat relate to [this thingy](https://github.com/Lazersmoke/ghost-buster/blob/master/src/Data/SuchThat.hs#L22) I wrote recently. IDK if it will help with what you are doing, though.

Comment: This would require ImpredicateTypes (which doesn't really work), as the application `f (+)` would require instantiating `a` in the type of `f` to `forall x . Num x => x -> x -> x`. If your goal is to have a simple syntax for function symbols, consider using TH - you will be able to analyze the actual polymorphic type of the argument.